# Javascript check if object properties are equal

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function that loops through an object that currently returns 5 values. The last value it returns will always be undefined.

I would like to execute some code only **if all 4** `value.valueId === 2`

This is what I have right now

```
Object.values(answers['3']).forEach(value => {
    console.log('checkboxValues', value.valueId)
    if (value.valueId === 2) {
      console.log('I AM 2')
    } else {
      console.log('I AM SOMETHING ELSE')
    }
  })
```

How do I check if all `value.valueId` === 2 ?

Comment: What is `answers[3]`? - don't see `answers` array defined anywhere.

Comment: `answers` is an object, the function is executing code on the 3rd nested object that is inside of `answers`

Comment: this is not a a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Just use 'every'. Info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp

```
Object.values(answers['3']).every(value => {
    return value.valueId === 2;
})
```

Here is it as an if statement:

```
if (Object.values(answers['3']).every(v => v.valueId === 2)) {
    // do success case
}
```

Comment: Cheers bro, didn't know about `.every`